# Comment « moment » a-t-il évolué de « courte durée » pour signifier « importance » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [moment (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=moment&searchmode=none) [<--] mid-14c., "very brief portion of time, instant," in moment of time,
>
> from Old French ***moment*** (12c.) "moment, minute; **importance**, weight, value"
>
> or directly from Latin *momentum* "movement, motion; moving power; alteration, *change;" also "short time, instant" [...], contraction of * *movimentum*, from movere* "to move" (see [move](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=move&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)).
>
> Some (but not OED) explain the sense evolution of the Latin word by notion of a particle so small it would just "move" the pointer of a scale, which led to the transferred sense of "minute time division." Sense of "importance, 'weight' " is attested in English from 1520s.

*momentum* (l'étymon latin) semble un « contronym », car il signifie initialement une courte durée et un temps bref, qui contredisent l'acception ultérieure de l'importance.

Prière de dévoiler et expliquer tous les changements sémantiques dissimulés et manquants. 
Comment est-ce que les sauts sémantiques se sont écartés du sens littéral original ?
Comment rapprocher les acceptions ultérieures (figurées)  des acceptions originales ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je voudrais revenir sur ta première affirmation, à savoir :

> Pourtant, ces deux acceptions *contredisent* l'acception ultérieure de l'importance

Ici, c'est le mot latin *[momentum](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=momentum)* qui a pour sens :

> - Mouvement, impulsion ; **poids** établissant ou rompant l’équilibre de la balance.
> - Poids, influence, **importance**, motif, cause.
> - Mouvement, écoulement du temps : **court intervalle de temps**, moment, minute.

Ainsi, le mot français puis anglais ont prit le sens du mot latin puisque c'était leur origine.

Et, il s'agit bien d'un usage **ultérieur** qui a affiné le sens du mot français pour ne conserver que la signification de *court intervalle de temps* !

> mid-14c., "very brief portion of time, instant,"

---

Pour comprendre comment le sens de mouvement a pu donner un instant, il faut se baser sur le sens de *"poids établissant ou rompant l’équilibre de la balance"*.

Celui-ci a donné le sens de variation et d'influence, et celles-ci ayant une durée très courte dans le temps, il n'y avait qu'un pas à faire pour désigner cette durée.

Answer (score 2):

Dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14284) on a étayé les sens du mot latin d'origine (*momentum*) et un segment de l'évolution du sens de *moment*. En complément, sur la nature de l'[emprûnt](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8360841) et la variété des sources :

> **Étymol. et Hist.** *A. 1.* **1119** « très petit espace de temps » (Philippe de Thaon, *Comput*, éd. E. Mall, 2321: ***Momenz*** e
>   atometes); [...] *2. a)* **1604** « *espace de temps de durée
>   indéterminée* » [...]  **3.** **1654-59** « occasion, circonstance ».
>   [...]  **B. 1.** **1634** « *produit d'un bras de levier par la force
>   qui lui est appliquée perpendiculairement* » (M. Mersenne, *Les
>   Méchaniques de Galilée*, chap.2, p.7); [...]  **B 1** empr. au lat.
>   *momentum* au sens de « *poussée d'un poids* ». Terme employé dans le lang. sc. dep. le début du XVII<sup>e</sup>s.: ital. *momento* chez
>   Galilée ds Batt.: *quella forza* [...] *con la quale il motor muove e
>   il mobile resiste...*; lat. sc. *momentum* au XVII<sup>e</sup>s. (F.
>   de Gandt, op. cit. infra); angl. *momentum* (1699 ds NED), *moment*
>   (1706, ibid.).
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé - TLFi, [*moment*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moment)
>   ([étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/moment)) ]

À l'origine concernant le mouvement, l'impulsion (dû à un poids sur la balance), on a initialement surtout emprunté le sens relatif au temps de *momentum*, et avec ce sens suit la *petite division* dans le sens temporel basé sur le petit poids (*DHLF*/Rey). Puis plus tard on a l'aspect *indéterminé* et le *moment opportun* et les locutions comme on le voit au *TLFi*. Mais il faut noter que pour B.1, en physique par exemple, c'est *réemprunté* au 17<sup>e</sup> avec le souffle de la *Renaissance* et vers les *Lumières*, quand on s'intéresse davantage aux sciences. Et donc on puise à nouveau dans le bassin latin, mais c'est pour des fins didactiques, et on « repasse sur le pli » de l'*action d'un poids* mais plus abstrait. Le *moment d'une force* vient ajouter son poids sémantique supplémentaire pourrait-on dire; l'influence du latin n'est pas toujours singulière ou linéaire (ou même valide, par exemple *sçavoir*) et elle a donc souvent plusieurs moments. C'est le cas ici.

En produisant la suite de la même entrée, on a un autre exemple d’emprunt, où on voit que même l'erreur peut être une source d'apport sémantique :

> **2** l'expr. *moment psychologique* est un calque de l'expr. all. *das
>   psychologische Moment*, utilisée dans la *Neue Preussische
>   Kreuzzeitung* du 16 déc. 1870 à propos du bombardement de Paris par
>   les Allemands, et dont le sens exact est « *facteur psychologique* »
>   (destiné à agir sur le moral des Parisiens assiégés et à obtenir leur
>   capitulation). Cette expr. a pris en fr. le sens de « moment opportun,
>   approprié » à la suite d'une erreur sur le sens de l'all. *das Moment*
>   qui signifie « *la raison décisive, le facteur* » et non « *le moment,
>   l'instant* » (*der Moment*). Voir E. Ritter, *Les Quatre dict. fr.*,
>   pp.464-465; Dub. Pol., pp.135 et 345; Lal.; *NED*, s.v.
>   *psychological*; Fonds Barbier.
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé - TLFi, [*moment*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moment)
>   ([étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/moment)) ]

Le *moment psychologique* est classé dans l'acception « *espace de temps favorable, propice (à quelque chose)* », et *appuie* dans cette direction.

L'emploi des mots change dans l'histoire selon les exigences de l'expression, entre autres, et les apports de sens sont multiples; les sens n'ont pas tous vocation à être compatibles vu les différents contextes.

Comment: Merci encore. 1. Que signifie `« repasse sur le pli »`? Est-ce une idiome ? Je sais qu'un pli = un tissu plié ou un sillon, mais comment peut-on y repasser ?

Comment: 2. SVP, pourriez-vous vous étendre sur ces phrases: 'on a initialement surtout emprunté le sens relatif au temps de *momentum*, et avec ce sens suit la *petite division* dans le sens temporel basé sur le petit poids'? Quelle est la *petite division*? Le sens temporel, comment se peut-il baser sur le petit poids?

Comment: SVP, pourriez-vous répondre aux questions supplémentaires dans votre réponse propre (et non pas à titre de commentaire) ?

Comment: @LePressentiment Repasser sur le pli dans le sens quand on plie une feuille et qu'on veut déchirer, on repasse sur le pli et donc la marque apparaît davantage. C'est une métaphore. La petite division pour le petit poids, par analogie... quelque chose de petit, avec qqc. de petit. Je vais y réfléchir davantage. Merci.

Comment: Je vous remercie de votre commentaire éducatif que j'ai plussoyé.

Comment: @LePressentiment Merci ! Le texte est un peu difficile, et en plus j'y ai fait quelques jeux de mots qui n'aident pas à la compréhension.